# Upload Files with specific name format

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

Is there any way so that a library only allows to upload files with the name which matches to specific format?

Example format:

> [Static name].[Actual year].[Unique number in the year][Static document
>   Extension].

If the file name is not matched with the specified format, it should not allow to upload the file in library.

Comment: I would use a[n] [Remote] Event Receiver for this. You can either perform a regex check and allow or deny the item to be added, or manipulate the file name to conform to your specs.

Comment: Hello, yes. I need this. I Will use Event Receiver. Sorry my english isn't good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this problem.
I am using Event Receiver that start when the item is adding to the library. If the name document is diferent to the default name, the library send a error.
I am using this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)